# v-menu attach not working inside vuetify datatable header filter

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, z-index

**Steps to reproduce**

> In the codepen there are two different datepicker used, when data is
>   present the datepicker is showing as expected, if the table is empty
>   while filtering, datepicker hides inside datatable

**Expected Behavior**

> The datepicker should be showing outside the footer instead of hides
>   inside the table

**Actual Behavior**

> When attach is used it should be sticky to the datepicker input box,
>   so that when horizontal scrolling happens, datepicker will also scroll
>   along with input box.
>
> At the same time, when no data is present in table both select
>   dropdown options and datepicker hides inside the table. Tried the
>   z-index for footer as well as datepicker. It didn't worked . Is this a
>   bug or is there any other way to handle this case

**Reproduction Link**

> https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/XWmamRP?editors=1000

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      hide-default-header
    >
      <template v-slot:header="{ props }">
        <th v-for="(head, index) in props.headers" :key="index"><div>{{head.text}}</div>
          <div v-if="index != 1 && index != 2">
            <v-select attach :items="items" placeholder="select with attach"></v-select>
          </div>
          <div style="position: relative;">
            <div v-if="index === 1" id="foo" style="position: absolute;">
            <v-menu
                    attach="#foo"
          ref="menu"
          v-model="menu"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          :return-value.sync="date"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
          min-width="290px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="date"
              label="Picker with attach"
              prepend-icon="event"
              readonly
              v-on="on"
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title scrollable>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="index === 2" >
            <v-menu
          ref="menu1"
          v-model="menu1"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          :return-value.sync="date"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
          min-width="290px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="date1"
              label="picker without attach"
              prepend-icon="event"
              readonly
              v-on="on"
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker v-model="date1" no-title scrollable>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu1 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu1.save(date1)">OK</v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
          </div>
        </th>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>


th {
  min-width: 250px;
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    menu: false,
      date1: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    menu1: false,
      items: [
        "dessert",
        "calories",
        "iron",
        "fat"
      ],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [],
      desserts1: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```